# What changed between 2 successive pytest runs

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to figure out which tests flipped their status since the last run? Status is either fail, pass or xfail.

Comment: `pytest` stores failures from the last run, so you can rerun only tests that failed by passing the `--lf` flag. For the tests that healed themselves etc  - I think this is something you'd have to implement yourself in a local plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the results in JUnit XML format with the `--junit-xml` [command line flag](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#command-line-flags) and compare them later in a reporting tool such as [Allure](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/). Or maybe one of the various reporting [plugins](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/plugin_list.html) can help you, such as the [pytest-historic](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-historic/), which I haven't tried.